# How to catch external events in php?

Tags: php, javascript, events, try-catch, external

Hi how can I catch an external event in php? does it possible. This event is raised from a .net application. Both are working parallely.

Using JavaScript I can raise external event. But how to catch that event. Please help me with a small example.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try AJAX to "catch" the event with PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exchange data between two different platforms then it is recommended to implement API. for example generate XML  or JSON file in .net and use something like Cron Jobs to automate the scan to look for any generated file, grab and read it. i have not implemented this. there may be better way to do it. i am not saying this is the only way you could go through. but i think this is one way out of it. while you can look for better ways to implement. the most important thing to remember is you have to develop your own API for the system to work.